# sed command not searching for string correctly and replacing

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, sed

I'm currently deploying a new webapp (GEM) for a project. When updating the user data, it's not correctly searching for the string and replacing it in the workers.properties file in apache. The current script I'm using to do this is:

```
sed -i "s/worker.list\=GMA,jkstatus/worker.list\=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus/g" ${INSTALL_BASE}/${APACHE_DIR}/conf/jk/workers.properties
```

the current line of code needing changed in workers.properties is the following:

> `worker.list=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus`

The change im trying to make is just this:

> `worker.list=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,GEM,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus`

Is there something not right in the search? It's changing other things in the file, so it's definitely able to access workers.properties. Any help on this is appreciated.

EDIT:
I have confirmed that it does not like the comma in between GMA,jkstatus indicating to start at GMA and end at jkstatus:

\=GMA,jkstatus/
So how do I tell sed to stop on jkstatus instead of using a comma?

Comment: Maybe `sed -i 's/worker\.list=.*/worker.list=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus/' ${INSTALL_BASE}/${APACHE_DIR}/conf/jk/workers.properties` will do?

Comment: Hey Wiktor sorry one thing. So with that it's editing the entire file and adding GAA, Launch etc to all of the "worker." I don't want it to edit the entire file. Just that one line. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean, only edit that first occurrence?

Comment: I'm testing in just a .txt file before I put into the user data so perhaps it's just the .txt file. Looks like it's just removing all spaces. This could be just notepad behaving funny. It seems that when I run that command it takes out all the spaces. Would this behave the same way within the workers.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match any text after `worker.list=` using `worker\.list=.*`:

```sh
sed -i 's/worker\.list=.*/worker.list=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus/' ${INSTALL_BASE}/${APACHE_DIR}/conf/jk/workers.properties
```

To remove only the first occurrence in the file you may use

```sh
sed -i '0,/worker\.list=.*/s//worker.list=GMA,ETL,common-resource,GAA,authzmanager,Launch,jkstatus/' ${INSTALL_BASE}/${APACHE_DIR}/conf/jk/workers.properties
```

Note `0,/pattern/` will remove only the first occurrence in the file.

Comment: The solution in the comments above fixed this. Thank you.

Comment: @dill03 I added both solutions.